# adjust UDP broadcast rate in python

Tags: python, network-programming, udp

I am using UDP broadcast in python to send packets to a stationary node from a moving node. What I want is to increase the data rates while the moving node approaches the static node and decrease the data rate when the nodes moves away so that I can transfer more amount of packets to receiving node.

Actually I am performing an experiment for my thesis where I want to measure signal strength along with the distance relative to the static node. Hence based on the value of received signal strength, distance I want to adjust broadcast rates.

Any helps and suggestions would be very helpful.

Here is the code

```
from socket import *
import os
import time

# A dummy string that I want to send
a = os.urandom(1400)

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('', 0))
s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)


# Send data along with the sequence number and current time
i=0  
while 1:  
    if os.system("iwconfig wlan0 | awk '/Signal level/ {print $4}'|cut -c 7-9") >= -90:   #-90 dbm is set as threshold  
        data = (str(i)+"###"+str(time.time())+"@@@"+ a.encode('hex'))[:1400] # only send 1400bytes of data  
        s.sendto(data, ('192.168.169.255', 5000))  
        i+=1  
    else sleep('<broadcast interval>') # sleep until the next broadcast interval
```

I am quite unsure of how to adjust the broadcast rates so i don't have the code for it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using the [socket](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) library? If so, you have full control of when you're sending data and you can throttle how often it sends based on signal strength. If you already have code that sends the UDP broadcasts posting that will probably help.

Comment: Hi i have placed the code. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you want it done in a linear fashion you can use something like this

```
def calc_delay(signal):
   rate = 11 * ( float(signal) + 90 ) / 20
   return(rate)

rate_cmd = 'iwconfig wlan0 rate %sM" % calc_delay(signal)
os.system(rate_cmd)
```

This is assuming you'll get signal strengths between -90 and -70 and that the max rate of your wireless card is 11M . So in your loop you can sleep for the return value of this function. If the signal strength is a different range the 90 and 20 obviously need to change.

Comment: actually I am trying it on a moving vehicle say at about 20 km/hr. Also I want to ask if I can set the broadcast rates. e.g. 1mbps when it is far and 5mbps when closer.

Comment: I think to do that you have to make a config change to the card. I took a shot at how to do that in the code, but it's really going to depend on your hardware. Good luck!

Comment: thanks , i am trying to look after it. i have atheros wireless card with ath9k driver. i have also looked into several forums for that. but still i dont know how to do it. If you and I have the same card than I think you could share it with me with what you have done.